# how do I check if users login via facebook or website log in system

Tags: php

How do I check if users logged in either any social media account or my own website login system. I also would like to echo out somethings according to whatever user logged in. When I try isset session it seperatly worked out. I could echo out but trying to check 2 variatons at the same time than it didn't work.

this is what I tried. And obviously I didn't echo out what I wanted to display

```
<?php  

if (!isset($_SESSION['website_id'])) || if 
                (!isset($_SESSION['social_id'])) 
{

                       
}
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What "didn't work" ? Note that you have syntax errors in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use two times if

Here is how you can do it

```
if (isset($_SESSION['website_id'])) || (!isset($_SESSION['social_id'])) {

}
```

Comment: I wanted to change head bar logout to login when users in it appears logout and when they are out it will change to login  and it worked separately